# Importing data into schema: Row import failed with error: ('Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Every time I get to the importing phase after I have created my schema, the fact table will fail to import anything. It has something to do with the foreign key constraint, obviously, but I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

I tried SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and it didn't work, I tried altering STRICT_TABLES in the .ini and that didn't work either, though these seem like a work around and not a real solution anyway.

A select query on the fact table always reads null for all columns.

I tried populating the fact table first, I tried using staging tables, I tried importing all the data without keys, which works, but can never establish a connection with dimension tables and the fact table afterwards, I tried dropping the entire database and working with completely different datasets, I tried using temporary tables, I tried using very simple schemas, with just 2 or 3 tables, and always receive: Row import failed with error: ('Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Help would be very much appreciated as it seems like an incredibly simple issue that I cannot seem to figure out.

I took some screenshots to demonstrate that I have created the foreign keys and they populated the dimension table.

[image: table with key constraint]
[image: foreign key created]
[image: error received]
[image: dimension table populated]